# How to include "span" and "class" with submit button?

Tags: css, ruby, forms, hyperlink

How can I make the `new_value_path` actually be a submit button that creates a new value instead of just refreshing back onto itself?

My current new.html.erb:

```html
<h1>New Value</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

  <%= link_to new_value_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
```

I want to keep the `class: 'btn'` and the `span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"` I think it has something to do with CRUD, but I haven't found an answer that specifically deals with including a class and a span.

Comment: where do you want it to go when you click submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve the answer in the _form itself using f.submit